# Using Scala trait as a callback interface

Tags: scala, traits

I just started learning scala and trying learn myself by making a simple application, dicebot.

Here's the simple application which process this simple command.

> CommandRouter().run("dice roll 3d4")

```
package com.kwoolytech.kwoolybot

case class CommandRouter() {

  def run(command: String): List[String] = {
    val _command = command.split("\\s+").toList

    commandArray.head match {
      case "dice" => Dice.run(_command.tail)
      case _ => List[]
    }
  }
}


package com.kwoolytech.kwoolybot

case class Dice() extends Bot {

  def run(command: List[String]): List[String] = {
    command.head match {
      case "roll" => roll(_command.tail)
      case _ => List[]
    }
  }

  private def roll(command: Array[String]): List[String] = {
    val rollCmdPattern = "([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)".r

    command.head match {
      case rollCmdPattern(numTry, diceSize) => rollDice(numTry, diceSize)
      case _ => List[]
    }
  }

  private def rollDice(numTry: Int, diceSize: Int): List[String] = {
    (1 to numTry).map { x => scala.util.Random.nextInt(diceSize) + 1})
  }.toList.map(_.toString)

}
```

Btw, at the very first part of the application, I want to pass over a callback function, which will get called when the Dice Bot done its work.

> Dice.run(_command.tail, **callback**)

The thing is.. I am not quite sure what to pass over for the **callback** parameter.
If this was Java, I will define a interface like below but in scala, I am not really sure what to use.

```
interface KwoolyHttpCallback {
    void onWeatherJsonDataReceived(String result);
    void onWeatherBitmapDataReceived(Bitmap result);
}

private void initializeKwoolyHttpCallbackFunction() {
httpClientCallback = new KwoolyHttpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onWeatherJsonDataReceived(String result) {
       try {
            dataModel.setWeatherJsonData(result);
            queryWeatherBitmapData();   
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

I heard from somewhere that the trait is the interface but I am really not getting it.

```
trait BotInterface {
  def onReceiveResult(result: List[String]): List[String]
}
```

Could you please teach me how to use the trait as a callback interface?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is a callback taking a `List[String]` and returning a `List[String]`, there's no need for a *trait*, you can require a *function*:

```
def run(command: List[String], callback: List[String] => List[String]): List[String]
```

The `callback` is using a little syntax sugar for the definition. It actually gets translated into a type named `Function1[List[String], List[String]]`.

Now callers can use anonymous function syntax to pass in an implementation:

```
run(List("1","2","3"), l => { 
  l.foreach(println)
  l
})
```

We can even make this a little bit prettier by using a *second* parameter list (this is called [*currying*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html)):

```
def run(command: List[String])(callback: List[String] => List[String]): List[String]
```

And now we have:

```
run(List("1","2","3")) { l =>
  l.foreach(println)
  l
}
```

---

If you're still convinced that you want a `trait`, it's actually pretty similar to how you'd define an interface in Java:

```
trait BotInterface {
  def onReceiveResult(result: List[String]): List[String]
}

def run(command: List[String], callback: BotInterface): List[String]
```

Note that traits in Scala can have default implementations, similar to Java 8's default methods:

```
trait BotInterface {
  def onReceiveResult(result: List[String]): List[String] = result.map(_.toLowerCase)
}
```

And inside the `run` definition you'll need to call `callback.onReceiveResult(list)`

Comment: Hey Yuval, I appreciate for your help. I think I got the point. thanks!